# What is this SF Visual Search thing on my online store?

Tags: html, css, web

I found this what looks like a plugin on my online store and I have no idea how to remove it. 
It only appears in product detail page: http://heavenlynature.co.nz/shop/shower/berry-chocolate-dessert-soap

So far I have only found this plugin appear on Windows 7, Firefox 19. Can anyone shed a light?

Screenshot here:
http://francisthedesigner.com/images/bug.jpg

Here's the code it generated

```
`<div id="SF_VISUAL_SEARCH" style="display: block; z-index: 1990000; position: fixed; -moz-user-select: none; width: 360px; overflow: visible; top: -3325px; left: 1552px; opacity: 100;">
<div id="SF_ScreenLayout" style="opacity: 0.01; z-index: 1989995; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none; background-color: white;"></div>
<div id="SF_arrSurface" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1989990; opacity: 0.7; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block; background-color: transparent;">
<sfmsg id="sfMsgId" data="{"imageCount":0,"ip":"1.1.1.1"}"></sfmsg>
<div id="SF_SA_INFO" style="display:none;z-index:1990000;-moz-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select:none;user-select:none;width:324px;height:394px; background: transparent;">
<div id="SF_IIAD_0" style="height: 81px; position: absolute; width: 1140px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; overflow: visible; z-index: 12010 ! important; left: 381px; top: 646px;">
<div id="IIAD_PRT_INFO" style="cursor:pointer; border: none !important;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left: 2px;height: 10px !important; overflow: hidden; line-height:10px !important;z-index:1;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,Verdana !important;font-size:7pt !important;color:#777777 !important;text-decoration:none !important;" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = 'none';" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = 'underline';" title="Info">SaveNow</div>
<div class="SF_IIAD_TRANS" style="height: 81px; padding-left: 433px; z-index: -1; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: visible; opacity: 0.9;">
<div id="SF_IIAD_ITEM_0_0" class="SF_IIAD_ITEM" style="position:static !important; margin: -1px 0 0 !important; overflow: visible !important; text-align: center !important; width: 66px !important; padding-right: 3px !important; display: block; float: left !important; vertical-align: top !important; font-family: arial,sans-serif !important; font-size: small !important; line-height: 1.2 !important;">
<div id="SF_IIAD_ITEM_0_1" class="SF_IIAD_ITEM" style="position:static !important; margin: -1px 0 0 !important; overflow: visible !important; text-align: center !important; width: 66px !important; padding-right: 3px !important; display: block; float: left !important; vertical-align: top !important; font-family: arial,sans-serif !important; font-size: small !important; line-height: 1.2 !important;">
<div style="height: 13px;width: 66px;position: absolute;top: 40px;left:502px;text-align: left;overflow: hidden;background-color: #ffffff;border-top: solid 1px #b57634;border-right: solid 1px #b57634;border-bottom: solid 1px #b57634;">
<div style="border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;border-style: solid;border-width: 7px 0 7px 5px;position: absolute;top: 40px;left:502px;font-size: 0;height: 0;line-height: 0;width: 0;"></div>
<div class="SF_IIAD_ITEM_INFO" style="display: none; padding: 3px; position: absolute; top: 70px; left: 429px; width: 324px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 2px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(244, 244, 244); border: 1px solid rgb(172, 174, 176); z-index: 2; text-align: left ! important;">
<a style="display: block; width: 59px; height: 59px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; border:none;" target="_blank" href="http://www.superfish.com/ws/offerURL.action?itemId=-519949008&userid=509c342431d8d1352414244&sessionid=509c31232013113847-831-1721&dlsource=saven&merchantName=heavenlynature.co.nz&resType=SDC&price=$17.95&identical=0&position=0.2&br=ff&CD_CTID=p2028&clickSrc=1">
<img class="SF_IIAD_IMG" style="width: 54px; height: 54px; border: medium none; padding: 1px; display: inline; opacity: 1;" sfnoicon="1" sfimgevt="-1" src="http://di34.shopping.com/images/di/71/35/5f/71556b674d586144796166644b367a58363467-100x100-0-0.jpg?p=p3.253679ec7feeb2d276a0&a=1&c=36&l=8070993&t=130311183848&r=3">
<img id="SF_II_LOAD_0_1" style="width: 54px; height: 54px; display: none; border: medium none; padding: 1px;" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/inimg/img/as.gif">
</a>
<a style="border: none !important; height: 10px !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica !important; font-size: 9px !important; line-height: 9px !important; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; text-align: center; color: #111111; margin-top: -3px; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="http://www.superfish.com/ws/offerURL.action?itemId=-519949008&userid=509c342431d8d1352414244&sessionid=509c31232013113847-831-1721&dlsource=saven&merchantName=heavenlynature.co.nz&resType=SDC&price=$17.95&identical=0&position=0.2&br=ff&CD_CTID=p2028&clickSrc=4" sfprice="1">$17.95</a>
</div>
<div id="SF_IIAD_ITEM_0_2" class="SF_IIAD_ITEM" style="position:static !important; margin: -1px 0 0 !important; overflow: visible !important; text-align: center !important; width: 66px !important; padding-right: 3px !important; display: block; float: left !important; vertical-align: top !important; font-family: arial,sans-serif !important; font-size: small !important; line-height: 1.2 !important;">
</div>
<div style="position: absolute;padding-top: 22px;height:35px; left:671px; top: 0;" title="More results">
<div style="z-index:1;position:absolute;bottom:0px;right:0;height:10px;width:10px;background: url(http://www.superfish.com/ws/inimg/img/b2new.png) 0px -1px no-repeat;cursor:pointer !important; margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important; font-size: 0 !important;" title=" Close SaveNow SlideUp"></div>`
```

Comment: Did you ever find out? I see it on a lot of sites recently, for instance TNW and Amazon. But I'm quite sure I'm not running any extension that's doing that...

Answer (score 9):

CULPRIT for me - SmoothGestures in Chrome Browser.

I removed all my extensions due to this, then added them back one by one.

Unfortunately, the SmoothGestures extension was installing SF_VISUAL_SEARCH using SuperFish technology.

It pasted "Product Search" and "Visual Search" divs all over many web pages.

It even created buttons to hover over the original site's buttons if it was popular enough. Nasty piece of software.

It pops up everywere - in the middle of Google searches as if it were part of the real searcresults, on top of the main graysonline.com.au site, completely ruining the site, and anywhere else it thinks it can trick you into clicking on the completely irrelevant and rubbish ads.

Goodbye SmoothGestures - I loved you for a number of years. Pity you sold out.

Comment: Settings > Extensions > Smooth Gestures > Options, then scroll all the way down near the bottom and change "Enable Product Search" from "On" to "No, I don't like money"

Comment: Thanks mate, this was also stopping stackoverflow from working. I kept getting a stackoverflow security error. Your comment helped loads.

Answer (score 1):

i hate it when they do that ssshhi****.

i disabled the color picker extension and it is gone but i am not ruling out that the government is somehow involved (joke).

Answer (score 0):

i think its a browser add-on doing some xss on ya. and this is a possible duplicate of this question [Why is Cloudfront loading scripts in my web app? (I don't use it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197918/why-is-cloudfront-loading-scripts-in-my-web-app-i-dont-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

One plugin that installs this in Safari is Awesome Screenshot Plus.

In Safari's Extensions dialog box there is a checkbox for,
 **"Enable similar product search powered by Superfish"**.

Uncheck this to disable the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same thing as described above, but I would get some ads injected on some websites, but not others. Looks like the source of it was Awesome Color Picker (Chrome extension), even though the extension was disabled. Problem went away after uninstalling the extension.

Answer (score 0):

The extension in Chrome "MeasureIt!"(with exclamation point) was adding these for me. There are 2 extensions named the same thing in the chrome store.

Answer (score 0):

The extension add blocker which is a REAL live saver came with this crap of sh*t... you can disable it in it. The extension is great, but the irony in it to. Just disable it and move on.

Extensions->adblock->options->EasyList (recommended) unckeck the suck*r